# Using awk for rows with different number of columns

Tags: awk

I have the following information printed in the terminal and as you can see the number of columns in the first and second rows

```
Strms  Blocks   Compressed Uncompressed  Ratio  Check   Filename
    1       1  2,526.9 MiB    317.1 GiB  0.008  CRC64   rar.stadium.trace.xz
```

So, if I use `awk '{print $3 "\t" $4}'`, I will get

```
Compressed  Uncompressed
2,526.9 MiB
```

Which is not what I want. any idea?

Comment: is your column delimiter  `TAB`?

Comment: It is the output of `xz -l`. I think it uses space.

Comment: From the man page: "For machine-readable output, `--robot --list` should be used."

Comment: If your table uses a `' '` (space) between fields, and also has a space within fields -- you are going to have problems. What does the actual data file look like? (you have the alternative of using "fixed-width" fields in `awk` also) See [4.6.1 Processing Fixed-Width Data](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Fixed-width-data.html)

Comment: if it is fixed length, you can use `cut -c16-39`

Comment: As a quick workaround, you [might use](https://ideone.com/vCAsST) `sed`: `sed -n -E 's/ *[0-9]+ +[0-9]+ +([0-9][0-9.,]* *[MKG]iB) +([0-9][0-9.,]* *[MKG]iB).*/\1\t\2/p'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: What is that `file`? Do you mean first saving the output in a file and then use sed?

Comment: You may pipe it to your app output, no need for a file. It is just a common "syntax" for `sed` in comments, an example. You can see `<<< "$s"`, a variable, is passed to `sed` in [my demo](https://ideone.com/vCAsST). This is not important in my comment. The sed command may be of interest. I removed the `file` from the comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `FIELDWIDTHS` parameter with `gnu awk` to set widths of each field like this:

```
xz -l t.xz | awk '{print $3"\t"$4}' FIELDWIDTHS="5 8 13 13 7 7 99"
   Compressed    Uncompressed
     79.7 MiB       553.9 MiB
  2,526.9 MiB       317.1 GiB
```

Edit: last filed set to 99 to handle long file name if its need
Edit2: to better handle space and length of field
Edit3: `FIELDWIDTHS="5 8 13 13 7 7 *"` can be used.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `FIELDWIDTHS="7 8 ...`? (note the position of the `2`)

Comment: The Fieldwidth is not a constant.

Comment: No, but must be small enough to not interfere with the *largest* value of the next field. With `9`, the `2` in `2,526.9 MiB` will be truncated.

Comment: Although the method works for simple and small number, it doesn't fully work with multiple file names (rows) with different sizes.

Comment: It was just made a quick test and should be tested with more data than I had to see how it behave.  For me second field was 9.

Comment: @mahmood you can parse the first line to create FIELDWIDTHS. See my updated answer.

Comment: @mahmood updated to conform with end alignment and long filename.

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU awk for FIELDWIDTHS. Also, with newer versions of gawk you can use `*` as the final value in FIELDWIDTHS to represent whatever's left on the line rather than having to pick some number like `99`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make use of GNU awk, you can parse the first line to determine `FIELDWIDTHS`:

```
awk '(NR==1){ for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) {match($0," *"$i); f=f" "RLENGTH};
              FIELDWIDTHS=f; $0=$0}
     {print $3,$4}'
```

See [comment of EdMorton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56930481/using-awk-for-rows-with-different-number-of-columns/56931060?noredirect=1#comment100412050_56931060) for improvements to the above and the reasoning why.

If you do not have access to GNU awk, you can make the output of `xz` easily parsable by using the robot mode:

> The robot mode is activated with the `--robot` option.  It makes the output of xz easier to parse by other programs.  Currently `--robot` is supported only together with `--version`, `--info-memory`, and `--list`.  It will be supported for compression and decompression in the future.
>
> `xz  --robot --list` uses **tab-separated output**.  The first column of every line has a string that indicates the type of information found on that line:

For a single file, you are interested in the `file` line:

> The columns of the file lines:
>
> 2. Number of streams in the file
> 3. Total number of blocks in the stream(s)
> 4. Compressed size of the file
> 5. Uncompressed size of the file
> 6. Compression ratio, for example 0.123.  If ratio is over 9.999, three dashes (---) are displayed instead of the ratio.
> 7. Comma-separated list of integrity check names.  The following strings are used for the known check types: None, CRC32, CRC64, and SHA-256.  For unknown check types, Unknown-N is used,
>                    where N is the Check ID as a decimal number (one or two digits).
> 8. Total size of stream padding in the file

So what you are interested in is:

```
xz --robot -l file.xz | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"; print "Compressed", "Uncompressed"}/file/{print $4,$5}'
```

If you want it in human-readable format, you can use this function in awk:

```
function tohuman(size, t,u,s) {
    split( "B KiB MiB GiB TiB PiB EiB ZiB YiB" , u, " ");
    t=size; s=1; while( t>1024 ){ t/=1024; s++ }
    return sprintf("%6.1f %s", t, u[s]) }
```

Comment: That is good, but it prints the sizes in bytes rather than that automatically MB or GB values.

Comment: Good idea using dynamic field widths.  Shorten some, removed `()` and one `;`: `awk 'NR==1 {for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) {match($0," *"$i); f=f" "RLENGTH} FIELDWIDTHS=f; $0=$0} {print $3,$4}'`

Comment: Ups, this cuts the file name if name is longer than label `Filename`.  Could be solved by setting last field width to 99. `awk 'NR==1 {for(i=1;i<NF;++i) {match($0," *"$i); f=f" "RLENGTH} FIELDWIDTHS=f" 99"; $0=$0} {print $4,$7}'`

Comment: That method will fail if/when a column header string contains a regexp metachar or is a substring of another one. You can do it more concisely and robustly by using another gawk-specific feature, FPAT: `BEGIN{FPAT="\\s*\\S+"} NR==1{for (i=1;i<NF;i++) f=f length($i)" "; FIELDWIDTHS=f"*"}`. Both approaches will fail if/when the column header contains a blank of course - there's no getting around that but that's less common that a regexp metachar or substring appearing.

Comment: @EdMorton I did not update my answer but referenced your comment. Very valid point and excellent fix!

Comment: @kvantour sounds good but please do feel free to update your answer if you like and if you do then I'd just delete my comment. Entirely up to you.